# How to get the subdirectory in virtual directory of a sharepoint web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web, virtual-directory

I have a subdirectory called "Holidays" in my sharepoint virtual directory.
"Holidays" ahs other subdirectories like "2010,"2011,"2012"
I am trying to read the files under the subdirectory of holiday and display the lists of all the files.

I am not able to get a map to the virtual directory so far. 
How can i get a physical path map so that i can treat the path as a directory and write retrieve all the files than end with .html and display.

so far i have tried this

```
SPWebApplication _webapp = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;
ltr_test.Text = _webapp.IisSettings[SPUrlZone.Default].Path.ToString();
```

it gives me an output like this

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\mywebsite.com
```

what i am looking for is this

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories
```

what changes i have to make any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Well*, then you can put it as a parameter in [`Path.GetDirectoryName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) method?

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\mywebsite.com")
```

should return

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories
```